# Hibernate: HQL does not load the data, but criteria does

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have the following instructions in one *Transaction*

```
(0)Transaction begins
(1)Insert A into myTable
(2)Load all data from myTable using HQL       #-> A is not loaded
(3)Load all data from myTable using Criteria  #-> A is loaded
(4)Transaction ends
```

But if I swap `(2)` and `(3)`, both cases are fine and `A` is loaded.

What would cause this problem?

---

**Details:** *Here is the code what I have*

```
@Transcational
myFunction(){
    //I have A inserted into myTable and the rest...

    SQLQuery crit = (SQLQuery) getSession().createSQLQuery("select * from myTable ");
    ArrayList<PatternHeader> ls = (ArrayList<PatternHeader>)crit.list(); //There is no trace of A

    Criteria cr = getSession().createCriteria(MyTable.class);
    ArrayList<PatternHeader> crls = (ArrayList<PatternHeader>)cr.list(); // A is loaded as well
}
```

Comment: Actually you're doing an SQL query not an HQL query.

Comment: Yeah I know. In fact the query was a bit different, but I changed it to this for simplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to the criteria API involves a flush, whereas the execution of the HQL statement does not. Probably your FlushMode is set to AUTO, which, as far as I understood, allows Hibernate to do what it thinks is best. Set the FlushMode to ALWAYS if you want to snych your session with the database before any query.

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to check your solution. I let you know as soon as I test your answer. BTW, how about `FlushMode.Always`? Is it not what you intend to do?

Comment: Oh. Of course! My fault. Always is your friend. See the edit of my answer.

Comment: Just tested your proposed solution. It turned out you were right. Please edit your answer and remove `I suppose` part since it is exactly the point, and your answer is accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Just adapted the answer :-)